# (Revised) Does p(a)=p(b) => a=b?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory

This is a revised version of problem posted here named :[Does $p(a) = p(b) \Rightarrow a=b \ $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387629/does-pa-pb-rightarrow-a-b)

Let $S=(P_1,P_2,…,P_n)$ be a set of polynomials with complex coefficients.

I call S critical if it satisfies 2 conditions.

1.set of solutions of ($P_n(a)=P_n(b)\ \ |\forall  n$) in $\Bbb C^2$ is (a=b) 
and

2.(ADDITIONAL CONDITION)(The subfield $K =\Bbb C(P_1(z),P_2(z) ,..,P_n(z))$ of $\Bbb C(z)$ does not contain z(i.e. K is a proper subfield))

I call a set minimal critical set if it is a critical set but no proper subset of it is critical.

Does There exist a minimal critical set?

if yes does there exist minimal critical sets of cardinality n for every n ?

What if we weaken condition ($a=b$) to {($a=b$) U (some finite points in $\Bbb C^2$)}?
 what about above questions?
((I think the set $(Z^2+Z,Z^4)$ works here  but i am not sure , i dont know whether $\Bbb C(Z^2+Z, Z^4)= \Bbb C(Z)$or not) ),

Comment: You should give a link to the previous version (and, if you intend to spend much time here, you should learn a little bit about formatting mathematics).

Comment: Yep, my previous (deleted) comment was precisely because you've chosen odd notation to describe your condition. In particular, putting a $\forall$ at the end of a sentence made me miss it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanx for the comment,  i gave the link for previous problem,  For formatting where can i find some help?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanx for help!